# Why does the MSDN library constantly say "Information Not Found"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Environment:
VS 2008 Pro SP1
MSDN Library for VS2008SP1

Sample Code:

```
        Dim userDataset = New DataSet
        Dim myDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT UserName FROM tblwebUsers WHERE name = @person", connect)

        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@person", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
```

When I put my cursor on the "d" in "Add" and press F1, I get an "Information Not Found" error from the MSDN Library.

Does anyone have any suggestions for addressing the issue?

Comment: Do you have MSDN installed on your computer? Alternatively, do you *not* have MSDN installed on your computer, and have Document Explorer set to load the help locally rather than from online? Also this is a question for stackoverflow. Also real programmers don't need to push F1.

Comment: @taspeotis, I disagree.  This is a SU question, there is no programming involved other than the fact that it is about an IDE.  Secondly, **real** programmers have API documentation open **all the time** as a reference.  Visual Studio just happens to advertise F1 as a quick way of accessing this documentation.

Comment: Yes, MSDN is installed. Humans are not generally known for their ability to memorize large quantities of unnecessary API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft `F1` help sucks!  It just doesn't work!  Using the MSDN library from the [Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library) is much more useful.  Personally, I have a firefox [smart keyword search](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Smart+keywords) and [search bar entry](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10072) for the MSDN library to help me work around this issue.

Comment: Is there anything like that for IE 8?

Comment: Try http://www.ieaddons.com/en/details/other/MSDN_Search/